# fb.ui send not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

Using fb.ui send in angularJS 1.6.
Tried both methods using JS in the HTML and then angular controller.
It sometimes works and most of the time doesn't. Tried in multiple browsers and laptops, same issue. (Very random)

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function facebookInviteInLine(){
        FB.ui({
            method: 'send',
            link: document.getElementById('element').value
        })
    }
</script>
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.facebookInvite = function(){
                    FB.ui({
                        method: 'send',
                        link: 'https://www.google.com'
                    })
                }
```

Is it a cookie cache issue or any other reason?

Comment: If it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't means it most likely is a timeout issue on the server you need to set a flag variable and continue to repeat until it always works. If it is a code issue it would always fail.

Comment: thank you. i will check on that. Still not working always.